# Proxy for debt service?

Tags: debt

I'm trying to get info on debt service relative to GDP for Morocco. I know these sorts of figures exist for the US, Japan, etc., since a few authors use them, but Trading Economics does not seem to have anything on that and they did a pretty good job of recouping all the available info from the two most reliable sources (central bank and statistics institute).

Are you aware of a good proxy for debt service (i.e interest + amortization) for the public/private sectors?

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

**There is data available on debt service for Morocco**. You do not need a proxy. Google is your friend. These are some hits:

- [Trading Economics 1](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/morocco/total-debt-service-percent-of-gni-wb-data.html)
- [Trading Economics 2](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/morocco/debt-service-on-external-debt-long-term-tds-us-dollar-wb-data.html)
- [World Bank](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=DT.TDS.DECT.EX.ZS&country=MAR)
- [Open Data for Africa](http://ethiopia.opendataforafrica.org/gwwnvqe/african-union-socio-economic-database?tsId=1119080)
- [Central Bank of Morocco](http://www.bkam.ma/en/content/view/full/14431) (open 2015 pdf, and search "debt service", and you will get the nominal value).